# Howto query all files, their fill level and additional drive info with one query?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, disk-space, datafile, compatibility-level

I need a query that puts together the following results:

- one row per database file across all databases
- additional columns with information about the locigal drive the file is on
- information about the size and the usage of the file

So far I have put together the following query:

```
    SELECT 
     GETDATE() as dt
     ,@@SERVERNAME as srv
     ,F.name 
     ,F.physical_name    
     ,Round(F.size * 8 / 1024, 2) as FileSizeMb
    , CAST(FILEPROPERTY(F.name, 'SpaceUsed') AS INT)/128 as FileUsedMB
    ,(F.size/128 - CAST(FILEPROPERTY(F.name, 'SpaceUsed') AS INT)/128) AS FileFreeMB
    ,Convert(decimal(18,2), (F.size/128 - CAST(FILEPROPERTY(F.name, 'SpaceUsed') AS INT)/128) / (F.size * 8 / 1024.1) * 100) as SpaceFreePerc 
     ,stat.size_on_disk_bytes / 1024 / 1024 SizeOnDiskMb
     ,drv.volume_mount_point, drv.logical_volume_name, drv.available_bytes, drv.total_bytes 
 FROM sys.master_files F 
 inner join sys.dm_io_virtual_file_stats(NULL, NULL) stat on F.database_id = stat.database_id AND F.file_id = stat.file_id 
 CROSS APPLY sys.dm_os_volume_stats(F.database_id, F.FILE_ID) drv
```

Now I face two problems here:

1. The FILEPROPERTY SpaceUsed is only available for the database in current context - so I need a solution to collect all Fileproperties from all dbs / files.
2. CROSS APPLY dm_os_volume_stats does not work for dbs with compatibility level 80, but I have some of those in place.

Is there a way to reach this goal with the given conditions? The solution does not have to be a one-statement query, since it will anyways be part of a stored procedure in the end.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To avoid `CROSS APPLY` the simplest way I can think of is to call `sys.dm_os_volume_stats` with explicit parameters for `database_id` and `file_id`. This means executing a single-row result for every db/file combo.

First, create a #temp table to hold results:

```
CREATE TABLE #x(dt datetime, srv nvarchar(520), logical_name sysname,
  physical_name sysname, FileSizeMb int, FileUsedMB int, FileFreeMB int,
  SpaceFreePerc decimal(18,2), SizeOnDiskMB int, volume_mount_point nvarchar(256), 
  logical_volume_name nvarchar(256), available_bytes bigint, total_bytes bigint);
```

Now, some variables and a cursor. The only tricky part here really is the `@exec` variable, which allows each iteration of the dynamic SQL to be executed in the right database context.

```
DECLARE @database_id int, @file_id int, @logical_name sysname, 
  @physical_name nvarchar(520), @size int, @sql nvarchar(max), @exec sysname;

DECLARE c CURSOR LOCAL FAST_FORWARD
  FOR SELECT database_id, [file_id], name, physical_name, size
  FROM sys.master_files;

SET @sql = N'SELECT 
     GETDATE() as dt ,@@SERVERNAME as srv, @logical_name, @physical_name    
     ,Round(@size * 8 / 1024, 2) as FileSizeMb
     , CAST(FILEPROPERTY(@logical_name, N''SpaceUsed'') AS INT)/128 as FileUsedMB
     ,(@size/128 - CAST(FILEPROPERTY(@logical_name, N''SpaceUsed'') AS INT)/128) AS FileFreeMB
     ,Convert(decimal(18,2), (@size/128 - CAST(FILEPROPERTY(@logical_name, N''SpaceUsed'') AS INT)/128) / (@size * 8 / 1024.1) * 100) as SpaceFreePerc
     ,stat.size_on_disk_bytes / 1024 / 1024 SizeOnDiskMb
     ,drv.volume_mount_point, drv.logical_volume_name, drv.available_bytes, drv.total_bytes 
 FROM sys.master_files F 
 inner join sys.dm_io_virtual_file_stats(NULL, NULL) stat on F.database_id = stat.database_id AND F.file_id = stat.file_id 
 CROSS JOIN sys.dm_os_volume_stats(@database_id, @file_id) drv
 WHERE F.database_id = @database_id AND F.file_id = @file_id;';

OPEN c;
FETCH NEXT FROM c INTO @database_id, @file_id, @logical_name, @physical_name, @size;

WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS <> -1)
BEGIN
  SET @exec = DB_NAME(@database_id) + N'.sys.sp_executesql ';    
  INSERT #x EXEC @exec @sql, N'@database_id int, @file_id int, 
    @logical_name sysname, @physical_name nvarchar(520), @size int',
    @database_id, @file_id, @logical_name, @physical_name, @size;

  FETCH NEXT FROM c INTO @database_id, @file_id, @logical_name, @physical_name, @size;
END

SELECT * FROM #x;

CLOSE c; DEALLOCATE c;
```

Comment: Thanks, very nice solution. One question since I now realize that the size_on_disk_bytes value of dm_os_volume_stats is always the same as size from master_files - does it make any sense to have dm_os_volume_stats included here at all?

Comment: @Magier Probably not, I wasn't evaluating that part at all.